# Cordova Tools for Visual Studio won't build

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

> Task Parameter:Language=en-US (TaskId:32)
>
> Task Parameter:BuildTarget=RippleNexus (TaskId:32) 
>   'C:\Users\ptaffet.SOHOSOFT\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-cli.cmd' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, (TaskId:32)
>   operable program or batch file. (TaskId:32)
>
> Done executing task
>   "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:32)
>
> Done building target
>   "PrepareForRippleRequirements" in project "rewordabble.jsproj" --
>   FAILED.: (TargetId:23)
>
> Project Performance Summary:

I recently re-installed Cordova Tools for Visual Studio and since then I have not been able to get a successful build, even for a new empty Cordova project. The snippet above comes from the verbose diagnostic Output.

As you can see, MS Build is looking in "'C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\" for a batch file named vs-cli.cmd. That batch file isn't found there. It's actually a couple of folders down in the file system, a location of "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda" along with a bunch of other batch files and other resources that will likely be required by the project at some point.

The build engine is looking in the wrong place for its own resources. How can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually this problem can be solved in visual studio by using the clear Cordova cache in options - tools - tools for apache cordova, then rebuild the project.  when you rebuild the project, make sure you have internet connection.

Comment: thanks. that got me past that error. now visual studio is throwing 15 new errors related to Microsoft.MDA.targets.

Comment: it's likely that the re-install is not successful.  are you using visual studio 2015 Community RC?  or Visual Studio 2013 Community update 4 with tools for apache cordova ctp3.1?

Comment: it's VS2013. I removed and reinstalled Cordova Tools twice now.

Comment: I got similar problem in 2013 and it's quite difficult sometimes to have clean re-install of cordova.  try to migrate to 2015 since 2013 cordova is going to be deprecated.

Comment: you may try to create a new user in Windows and rebuild the project using the new user id.  btw, 2015 can co-exist with 2013.

Comment: that is a great suggestion. vNext it is!

Comment: i tried many time, tried this, tried with proxy and without proxy, tried to do npm install crodova tools.. nothing work, my network is somehow slow, i'm wonder if it causing this, but is there any offline installation mode?